# I want to launch 2 .bat files from another .bat file

Tags: batch-file

bat  files from another Main.bat file

Files contain something like follows and i want both to launch in 15 seconds delayed and stay untill i close each one of them with a "Ctrl+C", can someone please help me with this Use Case please.

Main.bat

```
echo Task-1:
call C:\Users\user\bat\My_bat1.bat

echo Task-2:
call C:\Users\user\bat\My_bat2.bat
```

My_bat1.bat

```
start /wait cmd.exe /k "cd PATH && mvn -P dev"
```

My_bat2.bat

```
start /wait cmd.exe /k "cd PATH && mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,swagger,no-liquibase -Dspring.cloud.config.profile=dev -DskipTests=true"
```

Comment: which part fails?

Comment: @Dan: Both the .bat1 & .bat2 files start from the main.bat file and they close in 10 seconds, I want them to stay until i do the Ctrl+C and the second one should start 15 seconds delayed to first one as they both are launching 2 different microservices that are dependent on each other.  +OS is Win 10

Comment: @double-beep:No i want both to start at the same time or delay each by 15 seconds and wait in both the situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just asking how to delay your batch files by 15 seconds you can do it like this:

```
choice /t 15 /D y /n
```

If not can you please clarify your question?

EDIT: Based on your update, you want to add `pause` to your first child bat file, then the code above before the `call` command in your parent bat file.

Comment: Why did you go with `choice` over `ping` or `timeout`?

Comment: @SomethingDark because it works and I've used it since DOS 6.22? No other reason.

Comment: Both the .bat1 & .bat2 files start from the main.bat file and they close in 10 seconds, I want them to stay until i do the Ctrl+C and the second one should start 15 seconds delayed to first one as they both are launching 2 different microservices that are dependent on each other. +OS is Win 10

Answer (score 0):

You should really edit your question to include the sequence of events you want from the comments because it causes a lot of confusion.

I'll try to piece together what you want:

- Start job 1, creating a new window
- Do not wait for job 1 to finish, instead wait 15 seconds
- Start job 2, creating a new window
- If you press Ctrl+C in either window it should stop the job and close the window
- I assume that if one job is terminated before or after the other is started, the other still needs to start or continue to work.

First of all, the program that currently runs - in your case that seems to be `maven` - actually receives `Ctrl+C` and decides how it wants to act on it. I'm not sure if it does in the way you want it to.

### Main.bat

```
echo Task-1:
"%comspec%" /c "C:\Users\user\bat\My_bat1.bat"

timeout 15 /nobreak

echo Task-2:
"%comspec%" /c "C:\Users\user\bat\My_bat2.bat"
```

I added a `timeout` command between the launches. It waits 15 seconds.
If you removed `/nobreak` it would also be possible to interrupt the wait with a keystroke launching task#2 early

I find that `call` sometimes introduces wierd errors in such cases so I prefer `"%comspec%" /c`. It does the same thing except it does not receive back environment variables set in child file which is fine in your scenario.

### My_bat1.bat

```
start "" "%comspec%" /c "cd PATH & mvn -P dev & timeout -1 /nobreak"
```

I removed `/wait` which prevented the second `mvn` instance from starting until the first one is finished or terminated.

I replaced `/k` with `/c` and added `timeout` to pause execution in stead of `/k`.

The `timeout -1 /nobreak` statement causes command interpreter to wait indefinitely without a chance to stop it except for `Ctrl+C`.

You can remove `/nobreak` to allow it to be closed with any keystroke if mvn exited normally (if that ever happens)

`"%comspec%"` is the same as `cmd.exe` but is preferred if Microsoft ever decides to change command interpreter exe name. Empty `""` before is required because `start` interprets first double-quoted string as a window name.

I assume there is a folder named `PATH` inside current folder because it is not a variable. Furthermore, variable `%PATH%` is reserved for executable/library search path list and must not be assigned some random value or used with `cd` command unless you *really* know what you are doing. See `path /?`.

I also used `&` instead of `&&` to prevent window from closing if `mvn` crashes.

`My_bat2.bat` can be changed similarly.